# Is there an idiomatic French expression for "There goes my/your/etc. ...," meaning something you assumed you had suddenly disappears?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

You: My father just married someone half his age.
Me: There goes your inheritance.

You: I accidently shaved one eyebrow off.
Me:  There goes your dating life.

You: No, I didn't take the car in for that.  I just fixed it myself.
Me: There goes your warranty.

Answer (score 27):

An idiomatic reply to these sentences might be ***Tu peux dire adieu à** [...]*:

> *Tu peux dire adieu à ton héritage.*
> *Tu peux dire adieu à ton pouvoir de séduction.*
> *Tu peux dire adieu à ta garantie.*

Answer (score 22):

Beside the expression already given there is this following one.

> **faire une croix sur**

It is often used with the verb "pouvoir".

- Vous pouvez faire une croix sur votre vie amoureuse.
- Vous pouvez faire une croix sur votre garantie.
- Tu peux faire une croix sur ta garantie.

It is also found with other verbs or no verb at all.

- Fais une croix sur la garantie, elle (ne) vaut plus rien.
- Il n'y a plus qu'à faire une croix sur le pique nique, il n'a pas arrêté de pleuvoir.

Answer (score 7):

**C'est râpé.** Literally : *it's grated*. Figuratively : *it's over. There goes your ...*

> C'est râpé pour ton héritage.
>
> C'est râpé pour ton rendez-vous.
>
> C'est râpé pour la garantie.

[Le Robert, "râpé"](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/rape) :

> *familier* C'est **râpé**, se dit à l'occasion d'un contretemps, d'un espoir déçu. Pour mon voyage, c'est râpé ! ➙ *familier* **cuit,
> fichu.**

Comment: Je dirais plus "C'est perdu pour..."

Answer (score 6):

In a common popular french language, one can use:
**C'est foutu/fichu (d'avance)**
*Pour mon héritage, c'est fichu d'avance*.
*Pour la séduction, c'est foutu*.
*Pour la garantie, c'est fichu*.

Comment: I disagree with the 'd'avance' part. It is used in 'perdu d'avance' but not with foutu / fichu.

Comment: As a native, I use fichu d'avance quite often, less foutu d'avance, but sometime.

Answer (score 1):

*Larousse bilingue en ligne* [suggère](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/go/583806) une phrase comme « je peux abandonner tout espoir de », par exemple ici :

> *Je peux abandonner tout espoir* d'hériter/d'héritage.
> *Je peux abandonner tout espoir* de vie amoureuse.
> *Je peux abandonner tout espoir* de garantie.

Sans contexte ça devient parfois plus clair avec l'ajout d'un verbe (par ex. *...de me prévaloir de la garantie*).

On peut aussi penser à :

> *Tu peux oublier* ton héritage, ta vie amoureuse et ta garantie !

Comment: "There goes..." est bien plus familier que "je peux abandonner tout espoir de ..."

Comment: "tu peux oublier ..." est franchement pas mal, et n'a pas été cité jusqu'à là.

Answer (score 0):

Autant pour X !

(en évitant soigneusement que X = "moi", sous peine de faire vriller les enragés de l'*Au temps pour moi*). Ce que je crois être une traduction un peu directe de "so much for X" se rencontre périodiquement, bien que je la trouve hideuse, à titre personnel.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).